# How to get longlistselector selecteditem itemtemplate target?

Tags: c#, windows-phone

In my project I have a longlistselector (from the Windows Phone Toolkit).
I made a cutom itemtemplate to it and now I have to differentiate between
targeted elements in it.

For example I have some text and an image. If I hit the image I should
launch a WebBrowserTask to load the large image. If I hit the text I
should load the page that has the full article.

So I'd need somehow the targeted element in the ItemTemplate or I'd need
the data bound to that ItemTemplate.

Any thoughts on this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Bind the item you want to the Tag property of the image/textblock in the template, then capture the 'tapped' or 'mouseleftbuttondown' event and extract the item. That way you'll know which one it was.

In your XAML:

```
<DataTemplate>
   <StackPanel>
     <Image Source={Binding SourceField} Tag={Binding} MouseLeftButtonDown="myImage_MouseLeftButtonDown" />
     <TextBlock Text={Binding TextField} Tag={Binding}  MouseLeftButtonDown="myImage_MouseLeftButtonDown" />
   </StackPanel>
</DataTemplate>
```

In your C#:

```
private void myImage_MouseLeftButtonDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
   Image image = sender as Image;
   if (image != null && image.Tag != null && image.Tag is YourType)
   {
       YourType item = image.Tag as YourType;
      // Load the full image or browser or whatever you want
}
```

Comment: I got the same problem...
Thanks..Really appreciate.